# Generate Title of Calendar Event from value of other column

Tags: calendar

I created a calendar which has the columns `Title` and `Status`. The Status column can adapt one out of four string values which can be chosen with radio buttons. The thing I want to do is to automatically set the chosen value of the column `Status` as default value for the `Title` column.

I tried to use a calculated value formula without success.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a workflow.

[image: See an example screenshot here]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: To accomplish what he wants to do can be done with 1 or 2 lines of a SPD workflow.  I don't see how i didn't answer it without actually doing it for him and taking a screenshot of it.

Comment: you should give him steps to achieve this. some screen shots or at leaset right down the steps.

Comment: Ok, i've updated with a screenshot of the workflow needed to accomplish this.